# Android edittext phone format

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am implementing phone number format for edittext.
The problem is with limiting of phone length.

I am using PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher:

```
EditText telNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_tel);
telNumber.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

It doesn't limit the length of the phone number 
so I tried to limit the length of edit text in xml: `android:maxLength="16"`

**PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher** formats EditText by inserting spaces between some characters.
The problem is that for different region codes it shows different format and inserts different amount of spaces:
+380 50 555 5555 (16 characters) and
+380 5555 55555 (15 characters).
So in second case it allows adding one unneeded character.

How to fix this?
Maybe there is a build-in feature in PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher to limit the phone number?

How can I implement single format for all the region codes
to be:
+380 50 555 5555
+380 55 555 5555 ?

Comment: You got any solution for all country code ???

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're looking for is:

```
EditText telNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_tel);
telNumber.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
InputFilter[] filter = new InputFilter[1];
filter[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(16);
telNumber.setFilters(filter);
```

As for character limit, the only property applicable is the one you mentioned, `android:maxLength`. I'm fairly certain that `TextView` only counts input character not the characters it displays in the view in that criteria.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't help. What exectly this code should do?

Comment: It's supposed to give the user the same keyboard layout you get when going to "Phone" application (e.g. to dial a number) . The `InputFilter` part sets maximum number of characters allowed in the text field.

Answer (score 1):

You can unStrip the phonenumber that will remove unwanted character from edittext.

Try below code

```
String cell = _cellNumber_ET.getText().toString().trim();
    cell = PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(cell);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand how to use it. As far as I understand It removes front and rear spaces and then separators

Comment: Do you mean setting OnTextChangedListenner and check actual phone number length?

Comment: once you have got the final string from edittext then unstrip the string